# How to rescale a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am looking to rescale a list. So for example, I have a list that looks like this:

`__list = [[0,300,574,430,789], [0,0,210,487,342], [222,898,0,659,0]]`

But I want all the values to be rescaled so they are between 0 and 250.

How would I go about doing this - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So do you want whatever the maximum number (in this case, 898) and whatever the minimum number (in this case, 0) to be the basis of the scaling or something else?

Comment: Yes, 898 to be the max and 0 to be the min.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rescale in each sublist separately, you can use this code:

```
[[i * 255 // max(l) for i in sl] for sl in __list]
```

If you want to rescale globally, you can find `max` in all lists and divide by it like this:

```
max_ = max([max(sl) for sl in __list])
[[i * 255 // max_ for i in sl] for sl in __list]
```

Comment: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: Fixed with different name for list